# Trying to re-find a horror/suspense short story involving a painting

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

I remember in high school our class read a horror/suspense story involving a man who finds a painting at a garage sale. I can't remember many other details about it but would like very much to read it again. Would anybody know where the best place to look is?

Comment: Hi Keegan and thanks for visiting LitSE. Please take the time to go on the [tour] and to look in the [help]. At the moment you have a downvote and 2 close votes on your question, which may be because people think you are asking for story-identification, but haven't given much information. You've actually asked *where* you should look to identify it, which I is a different question and I'm not sure if it is on-topic or not. 1/2

Comment: If you ARE asking us to identify the story, please change the tag to [story-identification](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) and add as much of the information suggested by the tag as possible. 2/2

Answer (score 3):

If you don't remember many details it's hard to know for sure, but my instinct is [The Road Virus Heads North](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Road_Virus_Heads_North) by Stephen King. In it, a man buys a painting at a garage sale that he finds is changing in ominous ways. It's in his collection *Everything's Eventual*.